# How can I hold conversations with my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I was reading up on Pokemon Amie [Affection and Bonding](http://segmentnext.com/2013/10/12/pokemon-x-and-y-pokemon-amie-affection-and-bonding-guide/), when I came across this sentence:

> In some cases, you can also **talk to your Pokemon** to increase the Affection level but it is not that fast!

(Emphasis mine)

So far, my Butterfree & Frogadier seem to respond to their names but not much else. They seem to respond to talking in general by 'perking up', but then they stop being attentive without much else happening.

Are there specific sentences I can say to my Pokemon? Does it matter what I say at all? Or do they only respond to their name?

Comment: I honestly wouldn't be surprised if you literally have to talk at your 3DS microphone. (I don't know if that is actually the case or not)

Comment: @Unionhawk - that's what I mean, I'm talking into my 3DS whilst in the Pokemon Amie section. Froakie and Butterfree perk up when I say their names, but anything else that I say seems to be ignored. I'm wondering if that's all they pick up on, or whether there are set sentences or phrases I can say

Comment: Try yelling "pika-pika-chu" or "squirtle squirtle"

Comment: I've found Pokemon just kinda perk up at noise in general. Whether it's their name or not. I'd say that there are no actual sentences you can say or anything like that, as they're just programmed to respond to any kind of noise. Not putting this as an actual answer though, because I could be wrong. Just my experience

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 368, Official Kalos Region Guide says;

> You can also talk or sing into your Nintendo 3DS microphone to entertain your Pokemon through verbal communication.

So I take my headphones, turn on classic radio, turn volume at 100%, put headphones on 3DS mic and finally turn on Pokemon Amie.

My Mewtwo aren't such fan of classics but it gived him +2 enjoyment after about 30 second session. No more even after tuning Beetles and listening all "Here come the Sun" so this must be max. Didn't tryied dubstep through.

So it kinda works.

Comment: I read that as well, so it doesn't matter what you say, so long as the microphone detects sound?

Comment: For my findings, yes. It must be rythimc and loud. Talking "Mewtwo" to Mewtwo didn't work at all after him listening to songs. I think that we must simple test it :) @Robotnik

Comment: I've been trying out talking to my Frogadier. It doesn't seem to matter what I say, even whether or not a say it's name, so long as I say a few words it works. So yeah, seems like it just listens for something that "sounds like speech".

Answer (score 9):

I have actually managed this.

Unfortunately, I haven't managed to find a site to source, but it is possible. Playing with an Eevee that I have three hearts with, I called its nickname just playing around. When it seemed to hear, I told it it was adorable and it gave that little sound of excitement like when you pet it, though I did not see any hearts or notes. I continued to give various praise with the same results.

I have yet to try this with other Pokémon, but its actually rather fun to just talk to the Eevee.

Hope this helps at least some.

Comment: Just to note, I don't know if the heart level had anything to do with it, I just know that it was at three hearts when it happened.

Comment: I just tried this with a Lucario with no hearts of affection, and did not get the same reaction at all. So either it's related to the pokemon or, more likely, it is related to the amount of affection you have.

Comment: I'm thinking certain Pokemon react to different sayings themselves. For example, I don't think Lucario or Charizard like being called 'adorable', nor does Gardevoir like being called 'strong'.

Comment: It's possible. I haven't had time to research more on this, but I plan on it tonight. I have to admit though... Eevee is absolutely adorable on Amie. xDDD

Comment: I've been looking into this all week, they still don't seem to follow a pattern :/. My friend at EB Games gave me the 'Official Guide to X/Y' today (it was a damaged copy so he couldn't sell it) - I'm hoping it mentions something in there. I'll read it when I get home from work

Comment: Hopefully it does. Nowhere I've looked online mentions anything about the talking part, except for what you found. I've been looking since I posted the question, in the hopes of finding a source for extra or correct info.

Comment: The only info that I could find was the one in iber's answer unfortunately :/, although it seems that the Pokemon simply react to prolonged sound, talking and/or singing according to that answer. Thanks for your help however

Comment: @Kendra did you try calling him [Rucario](http://www.wimp.com/foreignaccent/)?

Answer (score 4):

My Banette (five hearts of affection) tends to enjoy hearing her name, but not much else. Yes, my Banette is female, and I've tried saying multiple things to my Banette (mostly praise). Though she does seem quite happy, no notes or hearts will pop up after I speak to her. Though she would not respond when she had no hearts of affection. I do believe it has to do with the level of affection, and I'm going to get Banette's level of affection to six hearts just to try this out. Hopefully it will help some people. My Banette doesn't really respond to her Pokémon name, and her nickname is in Japanese (I received her over the GTS) but I can't pronounce Japanese.

With Eevee (I've used both male and female), the adorable Pokémon loves praise and hearing it's nickname. I've tried playing a few songs for it from the radio, of multiple genres, and Eevee seems to enjoy most songs.

I tried speaking to Empoleon and Blaziken as well, and neither of the two responded.

I also experimented with hacked vs. Not hacked Pokémon. There is little difference. I then tried experimenting with Pokémon that I caught and Pokemon I traded, to see if the OT makes a difference. It does, pokemon of my own tend to hear their nicknames and respond faster than Pokémon I received from trading. I want to see if legendaries make a difference too, but haven't gotten to that yet.

Update: My Banette (six hearts of affection) now responds to her English Pokémon name.

I still have not checked the legendaries to find a difference.

Comment: If you received your Banette from GTS her name should be ジュペッタ, the Japanese one, and it's pronounced *Jupetta*.